# How do I itterate over a nested list to get a list of possible outcomes with unique elements in it?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, combinations

Given a nested list say:

```
a = [[1, 5, 100],
     [2],
     [2, 100]]
```

The desired **result** to be obtained is as follows:

```
[[1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 100], [5, 2, 100], [100, 2, 5]]
```

Here is my code, but it does not give the output as desired. I am unable to progress further:

```
arr = [[i] for i in a[0]]

def poss(j, arr, tmp):

     for i in range(len(tmp)):
          arr[i] = tmp[i] + [j]
     print(arr)

for i in a[1:]:
     tmp = [k for k in arr] # deepcopy of arr
     
     for j in i:
          poss(j, arr, tmp)
```

Output for above code:

```
[[1, 2], [5, 2], [100, 2]]
[[1, 2, 5], [5, 2, 5], [100, 2, 5]]
[[1, 2, 100], [5, 2, 100], [100, 2, 100]]
```

I also feel this code is inefficient on large data, is that so? I'm looking for a better code to get the result.

Comment: Where do you determine that all sublists should have 3 elements at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved by using itertools module of python.
The itertools.combinations() function returns all the possible subsets of the given set without repetition of elements.

```
import math
import itertools

a = [[1, 5, 100],
     [2],
     [2, 100]]

dimx = max([len(el) for el in a])

uniqueEls={}
for el in a:
    for subel in el:
        uniqueEls[subel] = uniqueEls.get(subel,0)

desiredArr= [list(x) for x in list(itertools.combinations(uniqueEls.keys(), dimx))]
print(desiredArr)
```

> [[1, 5, 100], [1, 5, 2], [1, 100, 2], [5, 100, 2]]

Comment: Brilliant! I was not familiar with ittertools module. I know it is stupid to not use this tool. But I would like to know to do it with simple for loops and if statements.

Comment: This link might help you
 https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/class-exercises/python-class-exercise-4.php. Please upvote the answer if you find it helpful.